# SyntaxError: invalid syntax in my random forrest scripting

Tags: pandas, sklearn-pandas

Below is random forrest scripting using python/pandas, which is giving the following error.

I have attempted to resolve the matter myself, however I am missing something.

'''
    X = X_train_std
    y = y_train

```
grid = dict(criterion = ['entropy'], 
        max_features = [11], 
        class_weight = 'balanced', 
        max_depth = [None],
        min_samples_leaf = list(range(1,10), 
        min_samples_split = [2])

rf = RandomForestClassifier(n_estimators=list(range(1,100)), 
random_state=0, n_jobs=-1)

clf = GridSearchCV(estimator = rf, param_grid=grid, cv=10, verbose=1, 
n_jobs=-1)

gs_rf = GridSearchCV(clf, grid, cv=10)

gs_rf.fit(X, y)

gs_rf.best_params_

print(gs_rf.best_score_)


print(gs_rf.best_params_)
```

'''

I expect an output similiar to the following.

'''
0.8838595239013255
{'min_samples_split': 2, 'min_samples_leaf': 4, 'max_depth': 4, 'class_weight': {0: 1, 1: 1}}
'''

but I am getting the following.

'''
  File "", line 14
    rf = RandomForestClassifier(n_estimators=list(range(1,100)), random_state=0, n_jobs=-1)
     ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
'''

Comment: missing trailing closing parenthesis: `min_samples_leaf = list(range(1,10),` you want `min_samples_leaf = list(range(1,10))#<-----here,` vote to close as it's a typo

Comment: Thanks, that cleared that error.